# Images load slowly after using an alert, why?

Tags: php, javascript, html, alert

I have a page that has the following php:

```
<?php
$mail = $_GET["mail"];
if ($mail == "true"){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mail sent successfully! Check your inbox!");</script>';
}
if ($mail == "false"){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mail sending failed, please try again later :<");</script>';
}
?>
```

It's index.php that only gets that variable from a mail sending php.

Problem is I had to put it at the end of body so the body loads first (and thus the alert pop-up doesn't show on a white background), but images doesn't load first and, after I click "ok" in the alert window, they load awfully slow (so I think they start loading after a while). Why could this be?

Comment: What do you see in Firebug or Fiddler? Which request(s) take a long time?

Comment: Apparently it had to do with an extension in chrome, after disabling it, they don't take that long, nevertheless I would prefer to load them first c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should wait for the whole page to load before making an alert.
See [here](http://makeagreatsite.com/javascript/how-execute-javascript-when-document-ready).

Comment: Since they were just 25KB in images I used the javascript one, it worked flawlessly, thank you very much!